# Field name with square brackets, can't validate

Tags: angularjs

my cms requires that I use `fields[name]` or `fields[email]` as input name. I'm having troubles using this name for testing its validity. Es. `{{contactForm.fields[email].$valid}}` returns null. How can I use the field name as is?

Thanks!

Comment: what about `{{contactForm['fields[email]'].$valid}}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{contactForm['fields[email]'].$valid}}
```